# Get formatted string through function return by getJSON

Tags: javascript, function, jqgrid, getjson

I'm trying to make a function ,this is getting a formatted string form JSON data by PHP.
But I can't get the formatted string by this function.

JavaScript code below:

```
function getJSON2Str(opt){
    var url='t4action.php',returnStr='',i=1;
    var textInfo ="";
    $.getJSON( url , 'opt='+opt, function (data){
        $.each(data,function(){
            returnStr+= this.opid + ':' + this.opcont;
            if( i < data.length ) returnStr += ';';
            i++;
        })
        //alert(returnStr); //<--here is works to show string 'returnStr'.
    });
    //alert(returnStr);  //<-- here is NOT works to show string 'returnStr'.
    return returnStr;   //<-- finally I want to return 'returnStr' for other use.
}

alert(getJSON2Str('getEduOption'));  //<-- here just show a empty string.
```

The t4action.php code is very simple,just return some data from database.Example like:

```
<?php
$returnArr[0]['opid']=2;
$returnArr[0]['opcont']='high school';
$returnArr[1]['opid']=5;
$returnArr[1]['opcont']='university';
$returnArr[2]['opid']=8;
$returnArr[2]['opcont']='elementary school';
$returnArr[3]['opid']=9;
$returnArr[3]['opcont']='research institute';

echo json_encode($returnArr);
?>
```

What should I do let the function works? Thanks!

I use it in jqGrid search properties like these:

```
.....
search:true, stype:'select', searchrules:{required:true}, searchoptions:{value:getJSON2Str('getEduOption'), sopt:['eq']},
....
```

I know that I can use **dataUrl** property with **buildSelect** to build the select element. 
But in my case, options are show in search and edit form but not in list table. 
So I try this way to let it work. If I use that function like below is works.

```
function getJSON2Str(opt){
    return '0:--;2:high school;5:university;8:elementary school;9:research institute';
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use `dataUrl` with `buildSelect` inside of `searchoptions`. I see no reason to use *synchronous* `value` defined as function. Inside of `buildSelect` you can do all what you need. The usage of `'opt='+opt` as parameter is not good. You should use `{opt: opt}` instead. You can either append `?opt=getEduOption` directly to the URL (`dataUrl: "t4action.php?opt=getEduOption"`) or use `postData` option of `searchoptions` which could be as a function if required.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, so the `return returnStr;` is executed immediately after that which returns an empty string.
You need to change the code to:

```
function getJSON2Str(opt,callback){
    var url='t4action.php',returnStr='',i=1;
    var textInfo ="";
    $.getJSON( url , 'opt='+opt, function (data){
        $.each(data,function(){
            returnStr+= this.opid + ':' + this.opcont;
            if( i < data.length ) returnStr += ';';
            i++;
        })
        if (typeof callback === "function"){
            callback(returnStr);
        }
    });
}
```

Use it:

```
getJSON2Str('getEduOption', function(returnStr){
   alert(returnStr);
});
```

In your case, use it like this:

```
getJSON2Str('getEduOption', function(returnStr){
     var searchParam = {search:true, stype:'select', searchrules:{required:true}, searchoptions:{value:returnStr, sopt:['eq']};
     //your search function
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want use it in jqGrid search properties like these:` search:true, stype:'select', searchrules:{required:true}, searchoptions:{value:getJSON2Str('getEduOption'), sopt:['eq']},` May it's works?

Comment: I know that I can use `dataUrl` property with `buildSelect` to build the select element. But in my case, options are show in search and edit form but not in list table. So I try this way to let it work. If  I use that function like below is works. `function getJSON2Str(opt){ return '0:--;2:high school;5:university;8:elementary school;9:research institute';}`

Comment: Sorry, it's not works yet. I'd tried any possible way to solve my problem. Maybe I will make a sample page later. Anyway thank you very much again.

Comment: @EthanChen: does the getJSON2Str work? it's the main question in this post. If you have another problem but not related to this getJSON problem, you should create another detailed question about it. Should not ask too many unrelated things in one question.